# Is there a way to 'soft revert' an old commit?

Tags: git, git-revert

Is there a way to revert an old commit without changing the files in the working directory?
I made a commit a while back, but the code that I committed wasn't ready and I want those changes to stay in my working directory as uncommitted changes so that I can continue working on them now.
I looked into the revert command but that changes the working directory.
I was thinking about checkout the old revision, resetting the head 1 and stashing the changes, but I already have the changes. I just want it to be as if I never made that one commit way back then, but I want the changes to the files to stay.

Comment: IIRC, `git reset` will do that

Comment: `git reset` can take you back to an old commit, but that's now what I need to do.

Comment: It appears that what you want is to revert, and get in your working tree, changes from a commit that is several commits back, but without reverting or losing the more recent commits like a merge or others' work etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is "no".

The longer answer: `git revert`—like all merge-oriented operations, including `git cherry-pick`, `git rebase`, and of course `git merge` itself—modifies a modifiable work-tree, using an index.  You can commit or stash your current work, or get a second work-tree (with another clone, or using `git worktree` if you have Git version 2.5 or later).

You can use `git revert -n`, which allows the work-tree to be dirty, but I would not really advise that here.

The way I would handle this is to make a commit now:

```
$ git add ...
$ git commit -m 'temporary commit, do not push'
```

Then, do the desired revert as a regular commit:

```
$ git revert <hash>
```

Then use `git rebase -i` to swap the order of the new revert commit and the temporary commit:

```
$ git rebase -i HEAD~2  # and edit the two "pick" lines
```

then use `git reset --soft HEAD^` (or `HEAD~1`, same thing) or `git reset --mixed HEAD^` to un-commit the temporary commit.  At this point you are in the same state (mostly) as you were before you made the temporary commit.

The (mostly) has to do with the index state: if you use `git reset --soft`, all those `git add`s are in effect now.  If you use `git reset --mixed`, none of those `git add`s are in effect now.

#### For experts only

If, before you start any of this, you already have some carefully staged state—for instance, from `git add -p`—that you want to preserve, this requires doing *two* commits, and `git stash` before the revert, with `git stash apply --index` afterward, is simpler.  This is because `git stash` actually *makes* two commits, and `git stash apply --index` extracts and applies those two commits, separately, to the index and work-tree.  (Then `git stash drop` the stash if all has gone well.)

Depending on how comfortable you are with `git stash`, you can even replace the whole sequence above with `git stash && git revert <hash> && git stash pop` to do it as a one-liner.  Add `--index` to recover separate index state.  (Note that if you typo `--index` and your Git version is not modern enough to detect the mistake, this will mash together the two separate commits and drop the stash.  This is why I like to use `git stash apply` instead of `git stash pop` here.)

If anything goes *wrong* during this process, you will need to know exactly what happened, and what to do about it, hence the "for experts only" header above this part.

Comment: Thanks!! That's exactly what I needed.

Comment: `git revert -n` was exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 26):

You can do something like

```
git revert hash_of_your_commit
git reset HEAD^
```

After that you come with unstaged changes of your reverted commit.

Answer (score 14):

This command usually works for me:
`git revert --no-commit <commit>`

Answer (score 1):

A great option, is to use `git apply`, which is a safe operation and doesn't edit local git history.

*This will soft revert the specific commit*

```
git show COMMIT_HASH | git apply -R
```

**How it works**

By using `git show`, we get the diff from a specific commit. Then `git apply -R` reverses those changes and applies them to the current repo (without commiting)

Answer (score 0):

```
git revert <commit-hash>

git cherry-pick -n <commit-hash>
```

Answer (score -2):

Another way to do this is to set a bad $EDITOR, like:

```
EDITOR=nope git revert <hash>
```

it'll quit out when trying to edit the commit message but have staged the changed already

Comment: Does not work for me, it opens vim (default git editor) anyway